# Array of BOOST Sparse Vectors with BOOST/CSTDINT Types; Failing, Why?

Tags: c++, boost

Good morning,

I am attemtping to do the following:

```
#include <new>
//Boost for sparse and cstdint
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector_sparse.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>

int main(){

   boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_vector<boost::int_fast8_t> *p = new     boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_vector<boost::int_fast8_t>[100];
   boost::numeric::ublas::compressed_vector<boost::int_fast8_t> t (12,2);

   p[0] = t;

   for(boost::int_fast8_t i=0;i<t.size();i++)
     {

    p[0](i) = i;

     }
   std::cout << p[0] << std::endl;
}
```

Which yields: [12](
Whereas if I use a standard type, i.e int, it would print the range as expected.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is this just not possible?

I appreciate uint8_t isn't actually that fast on a 32 bit machine, but I need to conserve memory.

TIA!

Comment: Post actual sample code. This example will not print `[12](`.

Comment: @Cory It is for me? ~/WORK/devel/cpp $ g++ -std=c++0x example.cpp -o test
 ~/WORK/devel/cpp $ ./test
[12](

Comment: @CoryNelson yes it will http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/31437a69533201d5 (see my answer for why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `int_fast8_t` is actually equivalent to a `char` (signed or unsigned) type and is treated as such when printed.

```
auto& data = p[0];
std::copy(data.begin(), data.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
std::cout << std::endl;
```

fixes that (by explicitely treating the values as integers, not chars).

Had nothing to do with arrays, sparseness, stdints or whatever. Just iostreams :)

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ed34614d2e75b203)**